# Search / find link inside .data()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Got a list saved by using .data(). How is it possible to find exact string?

```
$('body').data('mobilMenu' , $("ul#globalMenu").html());
```

list looks like (ul#globalmenu):

```
 <ul> 
  <li> <a href="t.aspx">t</a></li>
  <li> <a href="b.aspx">b</a></li>
  <ul> 
      <li> <a href="t.aspx">TEST </a></li><--HOW DO I FIND THIS in .data()
      <li> <a href="b.aspx">b</a></li>
```

I want to search for the word "TEST " and then get the url for that link. don't use .contains .. need to know excact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the data with:

```
var data = $('body').data('mobilMenu');
```

Find all `<a>` elements and use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to extract element with exact text 'TEST ':

```
var url = $(data).find('a').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === 'TEST ';
}).attr('href');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/rNN73/)**

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess:

```
var myList = $($('body').data('mobilMenu'));
```

Now you could access the list's content with `$(myList).find('*');`